# How can I insert 100000 rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO pantscolor_t (procode, color, pic) 
VALUES
('74251', 'Black', '511black.jpg'),
('74251', 'OD Green', '511odgreen.jpg'),
('74251', 'Black', '511black.jpg'),
('74251', 'OD Green', '511odgreen.jpg'),
('74251', 'Black', '511black.jpg'),
('74251', 'OD Green', '511odgreen.jpg'),
..........
..........
..........

INSERT INTO pantscolor_t (procode,color,pic)
VALUES
('74251', 'Charcoal', '511charcoal.jpg'),
('74251', 'Charcoal', '511charcoal.jpg'),
('74251', 'Charcoal', '511charcoal.jpg'),
('74251', 'Charcoal', '511charcoal.jpg'),
.............
.............
.............

 INSERT INTO........................
 INSERT INTO........................
 INSERT INTO........................
 INSERT INTO........................
```

I have 100000 rows like this but my insert statements bigger than 1000 rows. When I run the SQL statement in SSMS, I get an error:

> The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create csv file (or some file with defined field delimiter and row delimiter) and use "BULK INSERT" option to load file to database. File can have 100000 rows; there won't be any problem of loading huge file using bulk upload.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: +1 From code, you could use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class

Comment: Then I guess; it will be easy to convert into csv file.

Comment: You can also use `bcp.exe` : `bcp mytable in data.txt -S (local) -d mydatabase -T  -c`  (-T for truasted connection, -c for character data you can use it for tab separated files. You can see other options with `bcp --help` for example -t for field -r for row terminator in case your data is not tab separated or tab delimited)

Answer (score 32):

Another solution is to use a select query with unions.

```
INSERT INTO pantscolor_t (procode,color,pic)
SELECT '74251', 'Black', '511black.jpg'
UNION ALL SELECT '74251', 'OD Green', '511odgreen.jpg'
UNION ALL SELECT '74251', 'Black', '511black.jpg'
UNION ALL SELECT '74251', 'OD Green', '511odgreen.jpg'
UNION ALL SELECT '74251', 'Black', '511black.jpg'
UNION ALL SELECT '74251', 'OD Green', '511odgreen.jpg'
--etc....
```

`UNION ALL` is used instead of `UNION` in order to speed up the query when dealing with thousands of records. `UNION ALL` allows for duplicate rows whereas `UNION` will ensure that duplicates do not exist in the result set. For this scenario we don't want to remove any possible duplicates, so `UNION ALL` is used.

Answer (score 24):

```
INSERT mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
('1502577', '0', '114', 'chodba', 'Praha', 'Praha 1'),
('1503483', '0', 'TVP', 'chodba', 'Praha', 'Praha 2'),
/* ... more than 1000 rows ... */
('1608107', '0', '8', 'sklad', 'Tlumačov', 'Tlumačov'),
('1608107', '0', '9', 'sklad', 'Tlumačov', 'Tlumačov')
) AS temp (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6);
```

Comment: It useful when you build query in loop. Worked!. Thank you

Comment: Life saver, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Here some reference [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#e-inserting-more-than-1000-rows)

Answer (score 10):

By applying the following you should not have any error :

```
INSERT INTO pantscolor_t (procode,color,pic) VALUES ('74251','Black','511black.jpg')

INSERT INTO pantscolor_t (procode,color,pic) VALUES ('74251', 'OD Green', '511odgreen.jpg')

INSERT INTO pantscolor_t (procode,color,pic) VALUES ('74251', 'Black', '511black.jpg')

INSERT INTO pantscolor_t (procode,color,pic) VALUES ('74251', 'OD Green', '511odgreen.jpg')

INSERT INTO pantscolor_t (procode,color,pic) VALUES ('74251', 'Black', '511black.jpg')

...........
```

I tried it and it worked, of course you can use the excel to concatenate the values easily.

Comment: It would be pretty slow process

Answer (score 0):

Create a csv out.csv etc
Then use:

```
BULK INSERT 
FROM 'C:\out.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```